# grid.table to PDF cuts off values at the top and bottom

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid

I am using grid.table to output a data frame to a pdf file. 
The skeleton of the code is below. 
The txt file I have has all the information on it. 
The dataframe looks like this

Stock     ClosePrc      PrevClosePrc     PL
ABC       90            80               10
DEF       100           105              -5

the text file has 42 stocks and 4 coloumns 
add some headings 
add up the P&L

```
library(gridExtra)
BOD.Equity <- read.table("Equity.txt", fill = TRUE, nrows = 46)
BOD.Equity[,5] <- (BOD.Equity[,4] - BOD.Equity[,3]) * BOD.Equity[,2] / 100
names(BOD.Equity) <- c("Underlying", "Position", "Close", "Prev Close", "PL")
BOD.Equity[44,5] = sum(BOD.Equity$PL)
BOD.Equity[44,2:4] = 0
pdf(file = "Flash.pdf")
grid.table(BOD.Equity, show.rownames = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

The problem is the PDF file shows only from stock number 11 onwards to stock number 10 from the end.  In other words the output file is cutting off the top 11 lines (10 plus the headings) from the top as well as the bottom 11 lines (the last 10 stock names and the last line which is the 0's and sum of the P&L coloumn). 
It doesnt help to zoom the pdf file

Comment: have you tried to specify a width and height for your pdf file?

Comment: Hi baptiste, my apologies - I am new to this function and was looking for optional arguments in the gridtable function and not the pdf function. i will dig around some more in there becuase no doubt i can change font sizes and all sorts of things to - thanks for pointing me in the obvious right direction.